# Wordpress apply get_excerpt formatting to a string

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to apply wordpress' get_excerpt format to a string I pass to it.

I know the standard excerpt only works within the loop - but I'm hoping there is a function or something I'm missing that generates the excerpt when you don't manually define one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixed answer:**

You need `wp_trim_words()`. Yes - you're right. `wp_trim_excerpt()` doesn't play nice with passed strings.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words

`wp_trim_words( "I would like to apply wordpress' get_excerpt format to a string I pass to it. I know the standard excerpt only works within the loop - but I'm hoping there is a function or something I'm missing that generates the excerpt when you don't manually define one.", 5, '[...]' );` returns "I would like to apply[...]"

**Previous answer:**

WordPress uses `wp_trim_excerpt()` to generate excerpts.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt

You probably want some filtering on there too before you output (depending on the source of your text).

Comment: That doesn't work, and I've found that people recommend recreating the function essentially. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/using-wp-trim-excerpt-to-get-the-excerpt-outside-the-loop/7400#7400

Comment: Yep sorry - I didn't test properly. Updated now.

Comment: Looks good, not exactly the same as excerpt ( if I were to apply excerpt length filters and such - but it works ) - Thanks!